# Vue-loader removes id selector from <style> at runtime

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, webpack-style-loader, vue-loader

What I'm trying to do is to generate pdf file from html via [library](https://github.com/kblok/puppeteer-sharp)  I'm using. So I need to get concrete html and his css, then to insert the css in the html, pass it to backend and generate the pdf.

I'm using Vue.js and having some css in `<style id="myStyle">` tag and at runtime trying to access it by id, but the problem is that when I start my application vue-loader loads my css file in header without `#myStyle` id selector.

Here is my sample code:

```html
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <h3 id="testapp">Test</h3>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    name: 'app',
    data() {
        return {

        }
    },
    created() {
        var styleElement = document.getElementById("myStyle"); // it's null, because 
            //there is no element with such selector at rutime
        styleElement.setAttribute("class", "democlass");
    }
}
</script>
 <style id="myStyle">
#app {
    font-family: "Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    text-align: center;
    color: #2c3e50;
    margin-top: 60px;
}
#testapp {
    color: #2c3e50;
    margin-top: 60px;
}
#testing {
    color: #2c3e50;
    margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

And here is loaded css in `<head>` without id
[image: styleTag]

Can someone tells me:

- Why in `<head>` id selector from my `<style>` disappears at runtime
- Is there a way to make it stay there, so I can select my `<style>` by id
- Or is there any other way to get concrete `<style>` at runtime

Comment: The Vue loader will incorporate your component styles into the final CSS stylesheet bundle. The `<style>` tag is not added to the HTML. Why would you need to access a `<style>` tag at runtime anyway?

Comment: Because at runtime I need to get concrete html and his css, then to insert this css in the html and generate pdf file via library I'm using.

Comment: You should explain what it is you're trying to do as opposed to a problem you're having with a solution you've already decided on. This is a classic [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: thx for the note I edited it